# El análisis de código de github CodeQL, como se configura para que escanee código en php?

Tags: php, github

Supuestamente se puede, pero cuando quiero configurarlo, como voy a mostrar a continuación, me salta este error.
Languages from configuration: php Error: Did not recognize the following languages: php

desde ya muchas gracias, y si no se puede perdonen por la molestia.

.yml :

```
name: "CodeQL"

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    # The branches below must be a subset of the branches above
    branches: [ "main" ]
  schedule:
    - cron: '21 0 * * 4'

jobs:
  analyze:
    name: Analyze

    runs-on: ${{ (matrix.language == 'swift' && 'macos-latest') || 'ubuntu-latest' }}
    timeout-minutes: ${{ (matrix.language == 'swift' && 120) || 360 }}
    permissions:
      actions: read
      contents: read
      security-events: write

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        language: [ 'javascript-typescript' ]


    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    # Initializes the CodeQL tools for scanning.
    - name: Initialize CodeQL
      uses: github/codeql-action/init@v2
      with:
        languages: php


    - name: Perform CodeQL Analysis
      uses: github/codeql-action/analyze@v2
      with:
        category: "/language:${{matrix.language}}"
```

Comment: estoy casi seguro que el flujo de trabajo esta mal que tal si intentas con algo asi: [enlace](https://gist.github.com/arcanisgk/023dddf7d368f7499c0ff853ed19649c) me comentas si te funciona.